# HTML data in Excel cell. Excel changing values, causing invalid import into database

Tags: asp.net, excel, excel-formula, export-to-excel

I am currently trying to import an excel spreadsheet that contains product data for products on my website.

Of the various fields available for product import, one of them is the product description. In this cell, I paste the HTML data that I wish to be displayed on that product.

However, it would seem that sometimes excel decides to format this data on it's own, and after importing, the HTML is all screwed up. It's strange, because this does not happen on every product.

I've tried formatting the cells as "text", but that seems to have no effect. When I paste the values from the cell into notepad, I can see that every singe quote symbol (") has been doubled. For what reason, I have no idea.

The data looks correct when viewed in the cell, but it does not import properly, and the data is visibly changed when copied and pasted out of excel.

Any ideas on how to remedy this? How can I get excel to just ignore the data?

Comment: An example would be <div id="PDG-Team-Image"> is converted to <div id=""PDG-Team-Image"">

Comment: Sounds like a Conatenate problem. Basically excel uses the " to indicate a string for its VBA interface. Not 100% sure how your problem is happening but have a loot at http://support.microsoft.com/kb/141578 and it might point you in the right direction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try putting the HTML code in a single line with no breaks. For example:

```
<html><body><p><div id="PDG-Team-Image">Test</body></html>
```

I ran a quick test using the above simple HTML snippet. In Column A, I put the code with line breaks. In column B, I put the code with no breaks. I then copied the cell A1 and pasted it into Notepad, and then copied B1 and pasted it into Notepad. You'll see the first paste (A1) has the double quotes. The second paste (B1) has no double quotes.

[image]